# Sum of squared elements of vectors in a matrix is one? (Normalize all test samples to input to PNN)

Tags: matlab

I have a 2 x 121 matrix. I want to normalize this matrix such that the sum of squared elements of each column vector results to 1.

```
x1 = -4:0.1:8;
x2 = -4:0.1:8;
x = [x1;x2];
```

I have tried many methods.

```
x = [x1/sqrt(x1(1)^2+x2(1)^2),x2/sqrt(x1(1)^2+x2(1)^2)]
```

This last one results in a 1 x 242 vector. I need the result to be a 2x1 column vector where the original matrix is normalized before becoming input to the next layer. I cannot seem to figure this one out

Comment: Compute the squared sum first, then just divide each column (using indexing) by each value. you will need the fucntion `sum` unless you wat to write 121 "+" signs :)

Comment: If you implement your requirement, you’ll see that all columns will become identical, and equal to `[1;1]/sqrt(2)`. Maybe you want to normalize each row instead?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I tried your method and ended up with [0.5;0.5]. The step before I calculated x = [x1/x;x2/x]. Where each element of x1 and x2 was squared then joined to be x = [x1;x2] and summed x = sum(x). Is this your intention?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think you're right. Normalizing each row makes more sense

Comment: @eliboy8 So you want the normalized result such that when you square each element in a given row and then add those elements in the given row it adds to 1 correct? Also just to confirm when you say square you mean the element times itself right? or the square root?

Comment: The vector I'm dealing with is 2D (2x121). I want the entire sum of squared elements (each element squared) of each vector along this matrix to equal 1 @MichaelTr7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Column-Wise:

[image: Normalization Process]

```
x1 = -4: 0.1: 8;
x2 = -4: 0.1: 8;
x = [x1; x2];

%Squaring all the elements within the matrix%
X_Squared = x.^2;

%Finding the sum of each column after squaring elements%
Column_Wise_Sum = sum(X_Squared,1);

%Finding the normalization factors%
Normalization_Factors = sqrt(1./Column_Wise_Sum);
Normalization_Factors = repmat(Normalization_Factors,2,1);

Normalized = x.*Normalization_Factors;
%Checking%
sum(Normalized.^2,1)
```

---

### Row-Wise:

```
x1 = -4: 0.1: 8;
x2 = -4: 0.1: 8;
x = [x1; x2];

%Scalar(e1)^2 + Scalar(e2)^2 + Scalar(e3)^2 . . . = 1%
%Scalar[(e1)^2 + (e2)^2 + (e3)^2 . . . ] = 1%
%Scalar = 1/[(e1)^2 + (e2)^2 + (e3)^2 . . . ];

Squared = x(1,:).^2;
Squared_Sum = sum(Squared,'all');
Scalar = 1/Squared_Sum;
Normalized(1,:) = x(1,:).*sqrt(Scalar);

Squared = x(2,:).^2;
Squared_Sum = sum(Squared,'all');
Scalar = 1/Squared_Sum;
Normalized(2,:) = x(2,:).*sqrt(Scalar);
%Checking%
sum(Normalized.^2,2)
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: So the elements of each vector inside matrix x sum up to 1. For example, consider a vector [x1;x2] in x such that x1 = 0.47 and x2 = 0.53. The sum is 1 within that particular vector. Since x1 and x2 share the same ranges in my problem, the values within each vector of matrix x will be the same. So normalizing is basically the sum of squared elements (element-wise squaring) of each vector within x where x1 + x2 add up to 1

Comment: I think we need to add some diagrams to add some clarification. Do you have the expected result/matrix?

Comment: I used your column-wise method on a different matrix and it worked perfectly. I really appreciate your help!